# nested if clauses

Tags: conditionals

If I have 2 "if statements" next to each other, does the last "if" statement become embedded within the first "if statement"?

For example, "I will swim only if I go to the beach only if it is sunny outside."

becomes  "I will swim only IF (it is true that I will go the beach only if it is sunny outside)

The "only if it is sunny outside" is only acting as a conditional for the words "I will go the beach" instead of all of the words that come before it ("I will swim only if I go to the beach").

Is this a correct interpretation, or am I overthinking things and coming up with some magical rule that is not true, the rule being that if you have 2 if statements side by side, the latter if statement becomes "nested" within the first if statement?

I don't think this rule is true, but I would like a formal logic argument as to why this rule is not true. My only analysis as to why my "nesting" rule is false is that both "only if" clauses are independent and equal and therefore you cannot nest one within the other.

Comment: You’re trying to make English into symbolic logic. There is no one-to-one mapping because statements in English are often ambiguous. Statements do not “nest” the way they do in algebra.

Comment: @Xanne, thank you, so my assumption that the last "if" statement nests into the first "if" statement is incorrect because I am trying to apply algebraic principles to English and cannot do so.

Comment: Sigh!  "I will swim only if I go to the beach *and* only if it is sunny outside."

Answer (score -3):

- I will swim only if I go to the beach only if it is sunny outside.

In normal English this sentence is meaningless because the scope of the grammatical word "if" is unclear; is it as in this sentence?

- I will swim only if ( I go to the beach **only if** it is sunny outside).

This is equivalent to the following.

- I will swim only if (if I go to the beach then it is sunny outside).

In correct English, where two "if" do not follow one another, this would be as follows.

- I will swim only if in those cases of my going to the beach it is sunny outside.

If we want to keep to the very word of the initial sentence, the next construction appears the best that can be done but is probably not acceptable;  a comma in this context is very unlikely, except for the insertion of an adverbial.

- I will swim only if, I go to the beach only if it is sunny outside. (*This seems to be correct grammar since, constructions such as, for instance, "a relation is reflexive if and only if, for any and every a, a stands in that relation to itself" are correct.*)

If this is the syntax wanted, then the sentence belongs to a very rare context because the swimming is conditional to the truth of "if I go to the beach then it is sunny outside".
Therefore, if the sentence is to have a usual meaning, the parsing must be different. The following is a possibility in which the comma can be understood to introduce coordination, but still this seems to be ambiguous, as we see after the following.

- I will swim only if I go to the beach, only if it is sunny outside.

This is equivalent to the next sentence.

- I will swim only if I go to the beach and it is sunny outside.

The comma can be taken as another mark of "nesting".

- (I will swim only if I go to the beach), only if it is sunny outside. (*correct grammar*)

---

*Addition due to comments*

There are a few points to keep in mind when dealing with this question of logic and I'll try to introduce you to that.

Whether in mathematics or in languages, there is no difference in the *basic* structure of what is called *a conditional*, that is the type of logical utterance found in your construction. A conditional must consist of two *propositions*, let's call them A and B, and theyare related by a particular *connector*. "*and*, "*or*", "*not*" are connectors also. The connector called *conditional* is a little more complicated. The mathematical symbol for it is "→"; it corresponds linguistically to "if… then …". so, given the two propositions, A and B, you can write your statement symbolically as "A → B" or in normal language as "if A then B". The resulting statement ("A → B" or  "if A then B") is also called a conditional.

It is important to bear in mind that "if A then B" is equivalent to "A only if B", which explains the disappearing of "only" below and the placement of "if" in a different way, and answers one of your questions ([second comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/561976/nested-subordinate-clauses/561999?noredirect=1#comment1388973_561999): "*not exactly: Only if it is sunny outside, then (I will swim only if I go to the beach), is not the same as "I will swim only if I go to the beach and it is sunny outside." Because in the first sentence, if it is not sunny outside, then I can still swim, I just won't have the requirement that I have to go to the beach....I can swim at the lake or pool if it is not sunny outside.*")

Notice that in your construction you have three propositional variables;

S: I will swim only
B:I go to the beach
W: it is sunny outside

Taking one of the forms you use, "I go to the beach only if it is sunny outside", it is translated into symbols as "B → W", read "if B then W".

However, you have in mind a construction in which appear **two** conditionals: you use "*if*" twice; therefore, from the structure of a conditional described above,  either you relate  4 propositional variables or you use one of the conditionals as a proposition or, yet another possibility, the two conditionals stand in a relation of distributivity, which in the end amounts to a reduction to one conditional.
Which case applies in your construction is not clear because it has no recognizable syntax. There are modifications that will turn it into a correct English sentence without compromising the essential so as to keep to a meaning that is close; for instance I did not add a fourth variable.

Since the possibility of 4 variables is out, it remains  two possibilities.

The first (the second conditional is treated as a proposition) amounts to "S → (B → W)".
A literal translation into English gives this:

- I will swim only if (if I go to the beach then it is sunny outside).

This is not correct English; two consecutive "if's" are not found in English, and so you have to transform this construction so as to keep the meaning while the syntax becomes right, which is possible and can be made as I did above. Here is a better way.

- I will swim only if whenever I go to the beach it is sunny outside.

You have to convince yourself that "If I go to the beach then it is sunny outside" is entirely equivalent to "whenever I go to the beach it is sunny outside".

- I will swim only if (if I go to the beach then it is sunny outside).

In correct English, where two "if" do not follow one another, this would as follows.

- I will swim only if in those cases of my going to the beach  it is sunny outside.

If this is the syntax wanted, then the sentence belongs to a very rare context because the swimming is conditional to the truth of "if  I go to the beach then it is sunny outside".

Therefore, if the sentence is to have a usual meaning, the parsing must be different. The following is a possibility in which commas introduce coordination.

- I will swim only if  I go to the beach, only if it is sunny outside.

This is equivalent to the following sentence.

- I will swim only if I go to the beach and it is sunny outside.

As to the second possibility, that of a distributive connector, it is immediate by the addition of a comma, which according to parataxis amounts to coordination.

Therefore,

"I will swim only if I go to the beach only if it is sunny outside."

becomes

"I will swim only if I go to the beach, only if it is sunny outside."

which amounts to

"I will swim only if I go to the beach and only if it is sunny outside."

and finally to

"I will swim only if I go to the beach and it is sunny outside. (*stylistically acceptable English sentence*)

This is "S → (B and W)", which expands to

"(S → B) and (S → W)", or in other words, which is equivalent. In normal language this is

"If I will swim then I go to the beach and if I will swim then it is sunny outside."

or

"I will swim only if I go to the beach and I will swim only if it is sunny outside.

All of that is syntactically correct but stylistically undesirable and so the *stylistically acceptable English sentence* is what is retained. (That highlights one the important differences between mathematics and languages.)

In conclusion, it can be said that there are no other reasonable  possibilities, and that you are correct, as these  two sole possibilities detailed above are not at all equivalent.

---

*Further addition due to this [comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/561976/nested-if-clauses/561999?noredirect=1#comment1389058_561999): '*My only question now is: Can the words: I will swim.... only if I go to the beach....only if it is sunny outside"If this is the syntax wanted, then the sentence belongs to a very rare context because the swimming is conditional to the truth of "if I go to the beach then it is sunny outside"*'*

This is equivalent to this, below (if you agree with that).

I will swim only if whenever I go to the beach it is sunny outside.

In plain English, this a grammatically correct but contrived statement that in practically all cases you would condense, on a first stage of amelioration (but not sufficient) into the more readable equivalent which follows.

- I will swim and go to the beach only if it is sunny outside. (*equivalence of mathematical logic: "S → (B → W)" equivalent to "(S and B) → W"*)

Then you would swap the conjuncts.

I will  go to the beach and swim  only if it is sunny outside.

This is so because, if in mathematical logic conjuncts are commutative, it is often not the case in language. (I'll let you ponder the reason for that in the present case.)

Comment: thank you, so from what I gather: "I will swim only if I go to the beach only if it is sunny outside" CANNOT MEAN " I will swim only if (I go the beach only if it is sunny outside)"

Comment: not exactly: Only if it is sunny outside, then (I will swim only if I go to the beach), is not the same as "I will swim only if I go to the beach and it is sunny outside." Because in the first sentence, if it is not sunny outside, then I can still swim, I just won't have the requirement that I have to go to the beach....I can swim at the lake or pool if it is not sunny outside.

Comment: @IndiraSingh I'll have to make an addition to my answer, but as this is rather complicated it'll take some time.

Comment: @IndiraSingh i have finished the  fairly thorough explanation I mentioned to you and it is now in my answer; I hope there is no error, but if something seems wrong or if you still have questions or do not understand, do not hesitate to comment further.

Comment: thank you for your explanation. My only question now is: Can the words: I will swim.... only if I go to the beach....only if it is sunny outside" mean that the swimming is conditional to the truth of "if I go to the beach then it is sunny outside". This is a meaning that I was trying to avoid, but is this meaning, nonetheless, plausable (though very bizarre and in a very limited context)

Comment: @IndiraSingh There is an error in my answer at the start. I think that in fact the syntax of the sentence ("I will swim only if I go to the beach only if it is sunny outside.") is irreproachable. It remains to see what it means. Therefore I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @IndiraSingh I have changed my mind again and I think that the syntax is not acceptable.